# Python Recursive Data Reading

Tags: python, recursion, minecraft

**The following will make more sense if you have ever played minecraft. Since many of you have not, I will try to explain it as best as I can**

I am trying to write a recursive function that can find the steps to craft any minecraft item from a flatfile of minecraft recipes. This one has me really stumped.

The flatfile is kinda long so I included it in [this](https://gist.github.com/1989842) gist.

```
def getRecipeChain(item, quantity=1):
    #magic recursive stuffs go here
```

So basically I need to look up the first recipe then look up the recipes for all the components of that first recipe and so on till you get to items with no recipes. Each time I need to append the recipe to a list so I get a sort of instruction set of what order to craft items in.

So here is the function I have now(the one the does not work)

```
def getRecipeChain(name, quantity=1):
    chain = []

    def getRecipe(name1, quantity1=1):
        if name1 in recipes:
            for item in recipes[name1]["ingredients"]["input"]:
                if item in recipes:
                    getRecipe(item, quantity1)
                else:
                    chain.append(item)

    getRecipe(name, quantity)
    return chain
```

Here is the ideal output I am going for. It is a dictionary with the item name and quantity's stored in it.

```
>>> getRecipeChain("solar_panel", 1):
{"insulated_copper_cable":13, "electronic_circuit":2, "re_battery":1, "furnace":1, "machine":1, "generator":1, "solar_panel":1}
```

So the question is, how do I do it?

I know asking for people to do work for you is frowned up here, so if you feel this is a little too close to you just doing the coding for me, just say so.

Comment: Just saying, but I think your sample output isn't right...

Comment: Well, insulated_copper_cable isn't a base item, is it? Nor is electronic_circuit. It seems you want to get the base ingredients, not the complex ones.

Comment: [Shameless plug](https://github.com/vermiculus/mcraw) - I'd appreciate your input.  This is almost exactly the idea I was going for as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be elegantly solved using [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which supports addition:

```
from collections import Counter

def getRecipe(name, quantity=1):
  if not name in recipes: return Counter({name: quantity})

  subitems = recipes[name]["ingredients"]["input"]
  return sum((getRecipe(item, quantity) for item in subitems), 
             Counter())

print repr(dict(getRecipe("solar_panel")))
# => {'copper': 39, 'refined_iron': 10, 'glass': 3, 
#     'rubber': 78, 'cobblestone': 8, 'tin': 4, 
#     'coal_dust': 3, 'nothing': 10, 'redstone': 6}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is 2 fold. First of all, you need to be appending the items to the chain in the recursive call to getRecipe(). Secondly, I think the two functions is needlessly complicating things. I think just the inner one should do. Something like this is what you are looking for. I haven't tested it, but it should be close enough to get you started on the right track.

```
def getRecipe(name, quantity=1):
    chain=[];
    if name in recipes:
        for item in recipes[name]["ingredients"]["input"]:
            if item in recipes:
                chain.append(getRecipe(item, quantity))
            else:
                chain.append(item)
    return chain
```

EDIT: The comments are filling my lack of python knowledge, so here's a better solution.

```
from collections import Counter
def getRecipe(name, quantity=1, count=Counter()):
    if name in recipes:
        for item in recipes[name]["ingredients"]["input"]:
            if item in recipes:
                getRecipe(item, quantity,counter)
            else:
                counter[item]+=quantity
    return counter
```

Comment: His desired output is a dict, so instead of chain.append, you should do *chain.setdefault(item, 0) += quantity*

Comment: @campos: This won't work as expected, the value will not be incremented. A `defaultdict(int)` would be the ideal data structure here.

Comment: I've updated my solution, thanks for filling in my blanks on Python;-)

Comment: @giodamelio: It doesn't work if you give it a basic item as an argument: `getRecipe("copper", 1)`, which is somewhat inconsistent.

Comment: @NiklasB. True, and I have no clue how to fix that. I don't think that will be a problem though.

Comment: This solution also seems to mess up when a recipe output more then 1 item. For example `Counter({'rubber': 78, 'copper': 39, <snip>})` It outputs the materials to make 78 cables when you only need 18.