# Extract item, recipe metadata from Minecraft installation

Tags: java, python, minecraft

I'm open to solutions in both Python and Java; I haven't truly *decided* on which language to do [this](https://github.com/vermiculus/mcraw) in yet.

I'm writing a CLI application which reduces Minecraft items to a list of their raw materials (and more importantly, *how many* would be required, but that's beside the point).  To do this, I need to either extract or create and maintain a database of all items and recipes.  If extraction is possible, the database will be saved into McRaw's native format (CSV, duh).

Manually doing the following for each entity (here, a craftable item with `ID=123` and a decently simple recipe) in the game

```
mcraw   item add    123 --name "Test Craftable Block"
mcraw recipe add  1 123  2 321  1 231  2 213
```

would take / is going to take *forever*, but the editing capability is well worth the writing of the interface itself.

---

It would be much faster to be able to extract the information from Minecraft itself.  **I ask** first

- if this is possible, and
- how could it be done

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593901/python-recursive-data-reading (not my Q, but scary similar in thought process)

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find luck checking in the de-obfuscated minecraft source code. You can use the (unofficial) [Minecraft Coder Pack](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/index.php/MCP_Releases) to generate the files you need. There should be a couple of classes and enums that you can get (or write a script to extract) the information you need.

Sorry I can't be more specific. I don't have the source on-hand.